# I would like to know how to implement a clear button on visual basic, that clears the form of any drawn graphics

Tags: vb.net

I essentially want a function that can clear a form completely, it would clear the form of anything I've drawn on it, and leave me with a clear form.

A function that creates a new form would not work for me, and I need it simply to clear the form.

Comment: Please do not spam tags that are not related to your problem. Are you really targeting VBA or are you rather using VB.NET?

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried so far. Kindly read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0):

With form you mean Worksheet?

Since you said "drawn" I imagine you mean graphs. You can delete all graphs on a Worksheet via...

```
Worksheets("NAME").ChartObjects.Delete
```

...and the Input for the graphs with

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NAME").Range("YOUR USED RANGE").Clear
```